# Number-theory proof involving the Binomial Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-theorem

I am trying to prove the following: if $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $(a+b)^p \equiv a^p + b^p$ (mod $p$), where $p$ is prime. I am recommended to use the fact that $p \choose k$ is divisible by p for $1 \leq k < p$.

I am trying to set it up so that $(a+b)^p - (a^p + b^p) \equiv 0$ (mod $p$) by noticing that:

$(a+b)^p = \sum_{k=0}^{p}$ $p \choose k$ $a^{p-k} \ b^{k} =  pr $ $\sum_{k=0}^{p} a^{p-k} \ b^{k}$, where $r \in \mathbb{Z}$. However, unless I'm missing something, this doesn't seem like the best approach since I won't be able to isolate the first and last terms of this summation (which is what I'm looking for).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By factoring $pr$ out of your summation, you are assuming every term is the same multiple of $p$. Also -- what happens when $k=0$ and $k=p$?

Comment: Hint: Try and write the expressions out for $n=2$ and $n=3$ and see if you can obtain a useful pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**: $\binom{p}{0} = \binom{p}{p} = 1$

Comment: Thanks for the hint. If I understand the hint, it appears I can do the following: $(a+b)^p = a^p + b^p + \sum_{k=1}^{p-1}$ $(p-1) \choose k$ \ $a^{(p-1) - k}b^k$ = $a^p + b^p + pr \sum_{k=1}^{p-1}$ \ $a^{(p-1) - k}b^k$, for some $r \in \mathbb{Z}$ and then I'm basically done?

Comment: Yes you are done.